# Resize the cell of UICollectionView without the reload methods

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

How can I resize the cell size of `UICollectionView` without `reload` methods?
Just want to call following method on some event. I do not want to reload `UICollectionView` or any of its section or row.

```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                           sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I got the solution to my question with following line of code.

```
collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

N.B. To animate this resizing, use `UIView.animate` :

```
let duration: TimeInterval = 0.3
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() 
})
```

Comment: How can I do it with animations?

Comment: That also seems to cause the content-offset to get set to zero?!? Any way to prevent this?

Comment: this is great ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that Payal Maniyar's solution also works for  [UICollectionCompositional](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views) layouts as well.
In my situation, I had a CollectionViewCell which only embedded a UITextView. Compositional layout correctly figured out the initial size of the text view in the cell. (Side note: you do this by disabling scrolling within the UITextView since it is already inside of another scrollable view). The problem was as the user typed directly into the text view, I wanted to change the height of the cell without reloading it. I wanted to avoid reloading the cell for 2 reasons. a) the reloaded cell flickers as the user types, b) the text view loses focus; thereby, forcing the user to click on the text view again to continue to type. So my solution is as follows:

1. I have a cell with only UITextView inside of it where the cell is also the UITextView's delegate as such:

   ```
   class MyCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     @IBOutlet private weak var myTextView: UITextView!
     //this local variable used to determine if the intrinsic content size has changed or not
     private var textViewHeight: CGFloat = .zero
     ...
     ...
     override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      myTextView.delegate = self
     }
     ...
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Conform this cell to UITextViewDelegate

   ```
   extension MyCollectionCell: UITextViewDelegate { 

   func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
     //this assumes that collection view already correctly laid out the cell
     //to the correct height for the contents of the UITextView
     //textViewHeight simply needs to catch up to it before user starts typing
     let fittingSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: myTextView.frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
     textViewHeight = fittingSize.height

     return true
   }

   func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
     //flag to determine whether textview's size is changing
     var shouldResize = false
     //calculate fitting size after the content has changed
     let fittingSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: myTextView.frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

     //if the current height is not equal to 
     if textViewHeight != fittingSize.height {
       shouldResize = true
       //save the new height 
       textViewHeight = fittingSize.height
     }

     //notify the cell's delegate (most likely a UIViewController) 
     //that UITextView's intrinsic content size has changed
     //perhaps with a protocol such as this:
     delegate?.textViewDidChange(newText: textView.text, alsoRequiresResize: shouldResize)
   }
   ```
3. Then when the delegate receives the notification, perhaps saves the updated text and updates the layout such as this:

   ```
   myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
   ```

The best part of this solution is that you do not have to invoke [collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview) to resize the cell because you are not using the clunky FlowLayout to begin with.

Cheers!

Comment: I am using Compositional Layout as well and this doesn't work as perfectly for me sadly. Scroll position is changed for me sadly when I invalidate the layout. I even tried invalidating a particular section that too didn't work me :(

Comment: @NikhilMuskur Regarding Compositional Layout, it looks that `dataSource.apply(snapshot, animated: animated)` should be enough to call instead the `invalidateLayout()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm showing the video inside `UICollectionViewCell`. I've seen that `UIView.animate` doesn't work correctly for updating the height with fade animation. The below code works perfectly.

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
})
```

Comment: This worked for MacCatalyst app.